# Bug on ui-grid column display

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I've got a problem on my angular application. I have an ui-grid but sometimes, only the 3 first columns are display and when I click on a column header or refresh the page all the columns are visible.

Screen :

[before refresh or click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6plY.png)

[after refresh or click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYkFc.png)

The definition of the ui-grid is :

```html
<div class="perso-ui-grid" ui-grid="options" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-edit ui-grid-resize-columns></div>
```

Do you have an idea from where is the problem ?

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in Plunker?   show relevant code pls

Comment: This is not systematic, this bug is 3 times for 20 display.. it depends. And no, I can't reproduce it in Plunker :(